# Converting Cell Deletion Function From Swift 3 to Swift 5

Tags: swift

Here is my function for deleting cells in Swift 3. How would I write this in Swift 5?

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
        {
            if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete
            {
                foods.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Just omit the type `if editingStyle == .delete`. And `tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)` is much better than `tableView.reloadRows()` even in Swift 3

Comment: Yea. This worked much nicer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple refactorized `UITableViewCellEditingStyle` to `UITableViewCell.EditingStyle`
So now it should be

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCell.EditingStyle.delete {
        foods.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```